# Why did people in Digimon Season 2 forget what Digimon were?

Tags: digimon

In the second season of Digimon ("Digimon Zero Two"), there were several instances, in which the Chosen Children hid their Digimon from other people or pretended that they were dolls.

This seemed very strange to me, as during the events of Season 1, Tokyo was invaded by Digimon. Many people were rounded up by Bakemon, and eventually faced Vamdemon, as seen here:

[image: Digimon Adventure, Season 1, Episode 35]

Furthermore, the fight between the Chosen Children and Apocalymon was visible from the real world, to the point where the parents of the Chosen Children cheered them on.

---

However, in Season 2, the idea that "people knew what Digimon were" seemed to have been abandoned completely. Daisuke, Miyako and Iori seemed completely unaware of what the Digiworld was, and they hid their Digimon from their parents and siblings, or pretended that they were dolls.

Even more strangely, in Episode 17 of Season 2, they hid their Digimon from Taichi's mother, who should be *acutely aware* of what the Digiworld was, given that she watched her children go there to fight Apocalymon.

Weirder still, even Tailmon is hiding from Hikari's mother, as seen in this moment  in Episode 17:

[image: Digimon Adventure Zero Two, Episode 17]

---

My question is now: Has there ever been an explanation as to how humankind collectively just forgot about the events of 1999, which according to Season 1 should have been visible world-wide?

Comment: The same way that the human race in Doctor Who keeps forgetting about being invaded by aliens.

Comment: @Valorum Meaning, there is no canonical explanation for it?

Comment: Probably the same reason that Ash forgets how to Pokemon ever couple of seasons. It's a "[jumping on point](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JumpingOnPoint)" for new viewers

Answer (score 2):

After looking into it for a while, there seems to be **no in-universe explanation** for this behavior.

As Valorum stated in a comment, this is likely a "[jumping-on point](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JumpingOnPoint)" for newer viewers, who may yet be unfamiliar with the Digimon universe.

On a personal note, I find it quite strange that this choice was made, as by episode 17, newer viewers would already be accustomed to what Digimon were, and the universe in Zero Two could as well have been written as "People are aware of the existence of Digimon".